# Multiple onbeforeunload events

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, onbeforeunload

I'm facing a weird problem in my web application.

There's a listener for onBeforeUnload event where I'm prompting the user to confirm whether he really want to leave the page.

It's working fine and as expected. But I'm facing an intermittent issue. Sometimes, the onBeforeUnload event is triggered multiple times (around 100 times) at the same time. So I get as many "Confirm Navigation" popups. I'm not sure why these many events are getting triggered.

I confirmed with the users that they didn't press refresh or back button. I added some logging and confirmed the same.

It works fine in firefox and IE. Only in chrome, I'm facing this issue. 
The users are reporting this issue atleast once a day and they're restarting the browser to use the app again.

My question is why multiple events are getting triggered. What sort of actions can cause this to happen?

Note : My page has some iframes. But none of them have the listener for onBeforeUnload.

EDIT:

I'm adding the event using javascript as follows.

```
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
          return "some message here";
    }
```

Comment: How did you add listener on that event?

Comment: maybe beforeunload event triggers for each window object (also for iframes) on the page. try to check if the event triggers only for main window by logging `location.href` value

Answer (score 0):

You should add a variable and show the prompt only once based on that variable

```
var prompted = false;

window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    if(!prompted){
        // code here
        prompted = true;

        return 'You are leaving ....';
    }
}
```

Comment: It will work only once for the one page. It's bad because user may try to leave page without saving content (or doing something else) and the second attempt will be possible

Comment: Hi, I tried this already but it doesn't solve the problem.. The second event won't throw a warning in this case but it doesn't stop the page from navigation as well.

Comment: Maybe if you check if the page content (or whatever you have) has changed .. change back `prompted` to `false`